# Recursion to map phone number to strings

Tags: java, algorithm, strings, recursion

I am trying to solve the following via recursion: In a phone we have each digit mapped to a number.

Example:

```
1       2(ABC)  3(DEF)   
4(GHI)  5(JKL)  6(MNO)  
7(PRS)  8(TUV)  9(XYZ)   
*       0       #
```

I need to print out all the possible sequences of a phone number (example: `637-8687`).

I did the following that seems to solve it:

```java
static Map<String, String> digits;  
    static{  
        digits = new HashMap<String, String>();  
        digits.put("2", "ABC");  
        digits.put("3", "DEF");  
        digits.put("4", "GHI");  
        digits.put("5", "JKL");  
        digits.put("6", "MNO");  
        digits.put("7", "PRS");  
        digits.put("8", "TUV");  
        digits.put("9", "XYZ");  
    }  

    public static void printSequences(String phoneNumber, Map<String, String> associations){  
        if(phoneNumber == null || phoneNumber.isEmpty()){  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();  
        }  
        if(associations == null || associations.isEmpty()){  
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();  
        }   
        String[] letters = new String[phoneNumber.length()];  
        for(int i = 0; i < phoneNumber.length(); i++){  
            String seq = associations.get(phoneNumber.charAt(i) + "");  
            if(seq == null)continue;  
            letters[i] = seq;              
        }   
        printSequences(letters, 0, letters.length, "");  
    }  
private static void printSequences(String[] letters, int start, int end, String prefix) {  

        if(start == end){  
            System.out.println(prefix);  
            return;  
        }  

        String sequence = letters[start];  
        if(sequence == null)  
            return;  

        for(int i = 0; i < sequence.length(); i++){  

            printSequences(letters, start + 1, end, prefix + sequence.charAt(i));  
        }  

    }
```

The `String[] letters` has all the relevant digits (extracted from a `Map`). In this case it is `[MNO, DEF, PRS, TUV, MNO, TUV, PRS]` for phone `6378687`.

This code seems to work but does **not** for `637-8687`.  For `637-8687` it actually prints nothing at all!

I am trying to practice recursion, so could you please help me out with this one?  Also, is recursion actually the best approach on such a problem?

Comment: You forgot `Q` on `7` and `W` on `9`!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some comments from my side:

1. The `end` parameter is unnecessary. You can just test for `start >= letters.length` instead. Also, you might want to rename start.
2. It might make sense to wrap your algorithm in a callable method such as `private void printSequences(String[] letters)`, which just kicks off the recursion by calling `printSequences(letters, 0, "")`.
3. As to your bug, it depends on how exactly you are calling the method above (what is start and end).
4. Your test for `letters[start] == null` does not seems necessary if the `letters` array is well-behaved (i.e., does not contain `null`).
5. Recursion is a decent way to solve this problem.
6. Your bug comes from the fact that when you process "-" as a digit, you generate `null` in `letters`. When processing `letters`, you don't call your function recursively but just return. That way, nothing is ever printed, which explains the behavior you describe. The proper way to handle that case would be to call the method recursively without appending anything to the prefix (or to make sure there are no null entries in `letters`, which I believe is the better way, see point 7).
7. I would use a `List<String>` for letters. That way you don't end up with `null` entries.
8. Your `IllegalArgumentException` should describe the problem. For instance, it could say "Got illegal phoneNumber".
9. Your `digits` map should map characters to strings, not strings to strings. That way you don't have to coerce the character into string with `phoneNumber.charAt(i) + ""`.

Comment: Is recursion the best option for this problem?

Comment: Yes, recursion is IMO a decent way to solve this.

Comment: Posted complete code

Comment: Updated my answer, found your bug.